# Problema con Sockets

Tags: python, c++, socket

Mi programa se divide en un server alojado en una raspberry y programado en Python y un cliente hecho en Qt con C++ (Abajo adjunto código). He conseguido comunicarlos de forma correcta excepto por una cosa. La idea es muy sencilla, quiero que el cliente envíe algo `"Hola mundo"` y el server conteste con un `"True"`, pudiendo hacer esto todas las veces necesarias sin que varíe el resultado (`Hola mundo - True`).

El problema viene a la hora de ejecutar esa acción varias veces, es decir, cuando yo pulso el botón de ejecutar que he programado la primera acción se realiza a la perfección, mi server recibe un `"Hola mundo"` y el cliente un `"True"`. PERO cuando ejecuto más de una vez empieza la guerra, se me solapan los datos, es decir, el server recibe `"Hola MundoHola Mundo"` y el cliente `"True"` `""` y así sucesivamente.

Ando bastante perdido, creí que podía ser el bucle while de python o que una vez terminaba la primera acción era conveniente cerrar el socket y volver a abrirlo, es decir, usar un socket nuevo para cada acción, pero no he conseguido nada que funcione. Consejos?

**Codigo Server:**

```py
import socket 
s =socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("IP",puerto))
s.listen(10)

def repro(): 
   mensaje = sc.recv(30)
   message = 'True'.encode('UTF-8')
   sc.send(message)
   print ('Mensaje:',mensaje)
   sc.close()

while True: 
   (sc,addr) = s.accept()
   while True:
   repro()
   break
sc.close()
```

**Codigo Cliente en Qt:**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QHostAddress>
#include <windows.h>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    _socket(this)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);


}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::lectura()
{
    //Funcion receptora del mensaje del server:
    QByteArray datas = _socket.readAll();
    qDebug() << datas;
}

void MainWindow::onReadyRead()
{
    //Funcion encargada de mandar mensaje al server: 
    char check[10] = "32";
    _socket.write("Hola mundo");
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    //Al apretar el boton nos conectamos al Host y realizamos las funciones de lectura y escritura: 
    _socket.connectToHost(QHostAddress("IP"), puerto);
    connect(&_socket, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(onReadyRead()));
    connect(&_socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(lectura()));

}
```

Comment: Cuando envías datos a través de sockets, el sistema operativo puede decidir cómo hacer el envío. Puede decidir enviar inmediatamente cuando se lo pides o puede decidir esperar a tener más datos y enviar un paquete más grande o puede fragmentar un paquete grande en paquetes más pequeños. Eso es lo que sucede cuando pulsas el botón muy seguido.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. La cosa es que el socket responde a la perfección, puedo pulsar el boton de forma muy seguida y el server lo recibe sin problema, inmediatamente. Lo que no se como solventar es la repetición de los mensajes, es como que a partir del segundo click empiezan a sumarse las cadenas y en vez de Hola mundo y True, lo que sale es Hola MundoHola mundo [etc] y "True" "" "" [etc].

Comment: Eso es precisamente lo que estoy diciendo: ese es el comportamiento normal del socket, tú no tienes control sobre el mismo, lo controla el sistema operativo. Intentaré darte una respuesta detallada.

Comment: Vale, entiendo lo que quieres decir. Replanteo mi pregunta pues. Me explico, la intención de todo esto es crear un servidor orientado a la domotica que sea capaz de reconocer acciones, es decir, que si el cliente envia la palabra "persiana" el server sea capaz de interpretar el envio y ejecutar una accion, como activar un rele. Por lo que si no consigo que las cadenas lleguen bien, al programa le sera imposible reconocerla. Dicho esto, puedo implementar mi idea usando sockets? O no va a ser viable por lo que explicas en el otro comentario. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Cuando envías datos a través de sockets, el sistema operativo puede decidir cómo hacer el envío:

- Puede decidir enviar inmediatamente cuando se lo pides:

  - Datos en cola: `"Hola mundo"`.
  - Mensaje: `"Hola mundo"`.
- Puede decidir esperar a tener más datos y enviar un paquete más grande:

  - Datos en cola: `"Hola mundo"`.
  - Mensaje: *no envía nada*.
  - Encolas más datos: `"Hola mundo"`.
  - Mensaje: `"Hola mundoHola mundo"`.
- Puede fragmentar un paquete grande en paquetes más pequeños:

  - Datos en cola: `"Hola mundoHola mundo"`.
  - Mensaje 1: `"Hola "`.
  - Mensaje 2: `"mundoHo"`.
  - Mensaje 3: `"la mu"`.
  - Mensaje 4: `"ndo"`.

Tú no tienes control sobre cómo el sistema operativo enviará los datos, pero sí tienes control sobre cómo interpretar los mensajes que recibes. Mi consejo es el siguiente:

1. Añade a cada mensaje una marca de final de mensaje. Usa un valor que nunca vaya a ser parte del mensaje, por ejemplo una barra vertical `'|'`.

   ```
   _socket.write("Hola mundo|");
   ```
2. Al recibir datos, no los proceses, acumúlalos en un búfer.

   ```
   static std::string bufer{};

   void MainWindow::lectura()
   {
       //Funcion receptora del mensaje del server:
       bufer.append(_socket.readAll());
       qDebug() << bufer;
   }
   ```
3. Examina el búfer hasta encontrar una marca de final de mensaje, extrae los datos hasta dicha marca y deja el resto en el búfer.

   ```
   std::string lee()
   {
       auto final = bufer.find('|');
       std::string result{};

       if (final != std::string::npos) // Hemos recibido la marca final de mensaje?
       {
           result = bufer.substr(0, final);
           bufer = bufer.substr(final + 1);
       }

       return result;
   }
   ```

La implementación exacta corre de tu cargo, puedes ver un ejemplo de mi propuesta en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZFPU8IwEMXPzadY64yEUQGvLeCVs2cvIUkxTpt08scL8NnrkrRQccYZuXW3b9/@3oa37fOO8667V5rXQUhYKuO8laxZk0sPO0rv1oQ4L4oiVbANlbQlIV9GCbCSq62k3GjnYax6EMwbNyV7ksWBGWtbqQVN7ZIcf5rWUtIoZsEbqJRmNazSqhlWgk4OE5zKxjNWulD7/RFZMlUBTVN3qzFHUegW98F8DhvZGJeAlTBQM2iY5axfhnEbqR37lK8kQ44suZ8hXNiiI108Jf2JJQW7ViS7R3g5STAlGvlgdU8bgyvtcbfSKXF/wnxjECk/h@QmeFguIX8biPf5qY6Xij@O7zovL/NN0MIc/m9wRZBsfn9G48pYoPGJ@mNh@uhXDo1ZLfXOf4w6g2SKF/sTbNCP0W47xe2HiE@1wFfqum8)</kbd>.